# How to handle No Records found in visual workflow

Tags: visual-workflow, errormessages

I have a flow which works fine when it finds records, however the issue is when there are no records found I want to exit the flow nicely but having a hard time with that for some reason.

The error in the debug log is as follows: 
09:31:57.215 (215774819)|FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR|Probably Limit Exceeded or 0 recipients
|FlowActionCall|Notification

update: This happens regardless if the flow finds any records or not.  below is a picture of my flow and when the error occurs, at the end of the flow when I click the 'Finish" button on the last screen.

[image]

Comment: After more testing it seems my flow is ending as an unhandled fault no matter if it's a success or fails to find a record.  I'm getting this message no matter what at the very end of my flow.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I did, and if I remember correctly it was because I was trying to display a formula field in on the screen.  SFDC Wizard told me that was a current bug with Flow... it can't render formula fields on the screen elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was if I remember correctly was because I was trying to display a formula field in on the screen.  SFDC Wizard told me that was a current bug with Flow... it can't render formula fields on the screen elements.

Comment: Do you mind accepting this answer so this is no longer bumped to the home page by community? You may also want to [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/62646/edit) this answer with an offical statement on the matter, if one is avaliable.